# Mentioning academic concession when sending transcripts

Tags: resume, cover-letter, sickness

I am applying for co-op jobs through my school. Some require me to send a transcript. Last semester I missed a lot of school due to illness and did poorly, which I'm worried will negatively impact my chances of getting a job.

I am currently applying for [academic concession](http://www.calendar.ubc.ca/vancouver/index.cfm?tree=3,48,0,0) which would remove the poor marks from my transcript, but the process won't be finished by the time I have to send transcripts (it can take months to apply for academic concession).

How should I mention academic concession when applying for these positions to mitigate the harm from the bad marks in my transcript?

RE-EDIT: I do want to include in the question the process for academic concession really is highly bureaucratic, for instance I have been told in no uncertain terms one of the factors in decision making is how technical a doctors note sound and how "unlikely it would be for a student to have written it". I don't plan on mentioning this to an employer, but it is a fact that may affect the matter.

Comment: what do you mean by "Did Poorly" did u cleared your last semister or not please disclose it

Comment: Or don't. Answers to this question will very likely be purely opinion based, arguing for either way, which makes it a bad fit for a Q'n'A site like this which seeks to provide 'right' answers.

Comment: Why don't you tell me some pros and cons so I can decide for myself?

Comment: @shaan I passed one course, dropped one, and would have passed the other but failed the final.

Comment: @user16748 how can you apply for a job with out clearing your semister courses.(Is that ok for your company to have you in job even though you have not cleared the exam) please elaborate

Comment: Hey user, welcome to [workplace.se]! I think this has the core of a great question, so I'm going to make an [edit] to clarify it a bit. If you think I missed the point, or can find a way to improve it, please make an [edit] yourself too. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ask your co-op advisor (assuming you have one), they are there to help. Quite often they know the recruiters personally and could mention that you have special cercumstances.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I mention this when I apply for a job? If so how and where? I
>   can think of three possible places: resume, coverletter or make an
>   annotation on the transcript itself.

If you are determined to mention your illness, the proper place is within your cover letter.  There's no logical spot for this on your resume, and you should never embellish your official transcript.

You might wish to be careful here in mentioning your illness at all.

If this is a lingering or recurring illness, you might be raising a red flag with potential employers that you might not be able to meet the needs of a new job due to your illness.

Even if that's not the case, you might come across as someone who is simply making excuses for poor performance. That's not something you want a potential employer to suspect.

If your academic performance was otherwise stellar, and one bad illness triggered these transcript problems, it may be best to leave a deeper discussion about that fact to the interview process itself.

Additionally, you have not yet been granted a concession by your school. You should check in with your school's co-op office to make sure you are actually still eligible for co-op jobs under their rules, before you apply.

Comment: I e-mailed my co-op coordinator and he never responded.

Answer (score 1):

**You should not mention illness**. Your personal medical condition is your own business and should be of no concern for potential employers. If they inquire as to why your performance suffered (your words) during a brief period, explain that you had personal issues at that time which have since been resolved. If they ask for specifics, then politely decline to discuss the matter as it is, again, personal. Most employers will not pry any further and the few who do are probably not desirable places to work.

It would probably be most advantageous to apply for co-op opportunities where your illness or your potential academic concessions are not issues. That way your personal matters can remain personal and you can be judged by potential employers based upon your potential merits as an employee and not because of any preconceptions.

Comment: Edited for clarity